# htaccess: Only allow file access via the complete path, not the rewritten one

Tags: .htaccess

In my setup i have my CMS reside in a subfolder /sub and i rewrite all the access to the root to this subfolder:

```
## Rewrite www.example.com to the CMS home page: www.example.com/corporate/index.php
RewriteRule ^$ sub/index.php [L]

## Let the CMS process paths like www.example.com/corporate/about
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^sub/(.*)$ sub/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

## Search for real CMS files that moved, 
##  (e.g. www.example.com/flash/intro.swf to www.example.com/corporate/flash/intro.swf)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub/$1 [L]

## Let CMS process all paths that are not real files and directories, like www.example.com/about
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So now there is a file in the CMS that i'd like to be able to call for mantnance reasons, but i don't want this file to be accessible from the root for security reasons.
So,

```
www.example.com/maintnance
```

should NOT work

```
www.example.com/sub/maintnance
```

SHOULD work.

Is this possible to do with .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible - you just need to add a special rule for that file *before* you get to the rest of the rewrite. E.g.:

```
RewriteRule /maintnance$ - [F,L]
```

says that if the filename is "/maintnance", don't do a rewrite - instead give a 403 Forbidden response and stop rewriting.

But this isn't very secure. If I were you, I'd use some form of access control, either based on IP address or based on authentication.

Comment: Thanks, yes, there is access control via a token, i just wanted the additional security that you have to know the name of the subfolder to access the file (the subfolder name itself is not very human readable :) )